# Tips to Speed up Video Load Time on Website

Tags: html, video

I am finishing up a website for my business and stuck on this video loading part. My file is about 70mb, it's a background video. It takes a good 15-30 seconds to load upon entering the site which is extremely frustrating and then once it does load it lags most of the time. On a phone I can't get it to play at all.

This is an HTML template and I threw in the video that came with the site (10mb)and it plays and loads instantly. When searching about size however most people say 100-200MB shouold be fine and have no issues.

Anyone got any tips?

Here is my site: https://www.coastal-films.com/

And here is my video imbed code

'''

```
<section id="home" class="notoppadding text-light videobg-section"
                     data-videofile="files/uploads/coffee"
                     data-videowidth="1280"
                     data-videoheight="720"
                     data-videoposter="files/uploads/1690x1100.jpg"
                     data-videoparallax="true"
                     data-videooverlaycolor="#000000"
                     data-videooverlayopacity="0.6"
                    data-sound="false">
    <div class="section-inner">
```

'''

Comment: Reading some more forums I am no reading contradictory claims to that size being fine. Would others suggest using a file thats 5-10mb instead of 40+ Would this help that much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images & videos on your front page weight 170MB!
This is way too much to expect a quick page load.

### Reducing image sizes

I took the photo001.jpg as an example: it weights 1.62MB and has a resolution of 2686x2850px.

Considering that it is displayed at 510x541px on the website, you can recuce it to this size, and compress it. I use [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com) but a lot of apps can do the job. After resizing / optimizing, this image weights just 24KB.

### Server bandwidth issue

Regarding the videos, there is a bandwidth issue. Even with a 1GBps fiber connection, your server will deliver the videos at 500kbps maximum (I'm in France, it may be faster if you live closer to your server).

Let's take your Quickreel video: Weights 57MB for 23 seconds. At 500kbps it will take around two minutes to transfer. This i why you have so much lag: the server you are using is not able to keep up.

### Compress the videos

You can reduce the resolution (720p should be enough given the size of the video on your page), and compress it with a software like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/). I was able to reduce the size of this video to ~3MB.

### Use the right image format

Some of your images (nick.png as an example) use the PNG format. It is a very good format to save illustrations or any kind of image with a majority of solid colors, but way too heavy to save photographs. Use JPG, resize and compress to reduce their size.